# (C++) fstream win32 exception occured in title.exe [6284]

Tags: c++, winapi, exception

So I made the following algorithm to solve a problem, but I don't understand why it crashes when I use fstream instead of iostream. When I use lower numbers, for example (input e.g.:  1 4 5 ) it works perfectly with fstream, but if I use some larger input numbers (e.g:  3 987654300 210 ),it says "Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)". If I use iostream, it works great even with 9 digit inputs.

Yes, I have the parola.in and parola.out in the same folder with the .cpp/.exe and the .in has the input numbers and everything.

Ignore the algorithm and the comments, and just pay attention at the use of "fout" and "fin" please.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream fin("parola.in");
    ofstream fout("parola.out");

    int a,b,k; //VARIABILE ORIGINALE
    int ord=1; //NUMARUL DE ORDINE AL VECTORILOR
    int cifa=0,cifb=0; //NUMARUL DE CIFRE AL NUMERELOR A SI B

    int nrA[18],nrB[10]; //VECTORII CE CONTIN CIFRELE NUMERELOR A SI B
    int temp[9]; //VECTORUL CE CONTINE CIFRELE NR. A IN ORDINE INVERSA

    fin>>k>>a>>b;

    while (a>0)
    {
        temp[ord]=a%10;
        a/=10;
        ord++;
        cifa++;
    }

    ord=1; //RESET NR ORDINE

    while (b>0)
    {
        nrB[ord]=b%10;
        b/=10;
        ord++;
        cifb++;
    }

    for (int topkek=1; topkek<=cifa; topkek++)
    {
        nrA[topkek]=temp[cifa+1-topkek]; //ORDONAREA CIFRELOR LUI A CRESCATOR, IN VECTORUL nrA
    }

    for (int zomtan=1; zomtan<=k; zomtan++)
    {
        fout<<nrA[zomtan];
        nrA[zomtan]=-1;
    }
    fout<<nrB[1];
    nrB[1]=-1;
    for (int zomtan2=cifa+1; zomtan2<=18; zomtan2++)
    {
        nrA[zomtan2]=-1;
    }

    for (int zomtan3=cifb+1; zomtan3<=10; zomtan3++)
    {
        nrB[zomtan3]=-1;
    }

    for (ord=1; ord<=9; ord++)
    {
        if (nrA[ord+k]!=-1)
        {
            fout<<nrA[ord+k];
        }
        if (nrB[ord+1]!=-1)
        {
        fout<<nrB[ord+1];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may wish to make a [Minimal, Compilable and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCVE for short) It'll help people more easily interpret what's going wrong.

Comment: You are on a wild goose chase if you believe the problem is merely changing the stream type.  More than likely you are accessing array element(s) out of bounds, causing undefined behavior to occur.  Changing the stream type only exposes the bug(s) to you.

Comment: Use `std::array` or `std::vector` to catch your buffer overruns using your debugger.

Comment: yeah, I pretty much derped out in this code...I had to extend the nrA vector from [18] capacity to [19]...I can't believe that I was trying to access some unallocated slots in the vector. But the interesting part is why it worked with iostream perfectly.

Comment: I know that iostream and fstream don't modify the algorithm at all, and this is why it's so weird.

Comment: @Princess_Luna *But the interesting part is why it worked with iostream perfectly*  -- When you read or write out of bounds, you are causing undefined behavior.   More than likely, it is the accessing of the garbage data that causes the exception -- all you did when you changed streams is change the binary image of the executable in a way where now the accessing of the out-of-bounds memory causes the access violation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can occurs beause, as I suppose, you use 1 based arrays instead of propper 0 based

```
for (int zomtan2=cifa+1; zomtan2<=18; zomtan2++)
{
    nrA[zomtan2]=-1;
}
```

the problem will always occurs because you have wrote `zomtan2<=18`

and your array declaration is `int nrA[18]` wich I have said previously always casues problems.

These errors are everywhere in your code, so i suggest you to rewrite the program

Comment: He is also going of the end of the array in the while loops for 9 digit input

Comment: I know.  I just wanted to to call that out in case you wanted to add that to the answer.